# Sorting a Rails database table by a column in an associated model with additional scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails. I am trying to implement something like Ryan Bates' sortable table columns code (Railscast #228) on a legacy database. My question is very similar to "Sorting a Rails database table by a column in an associated model", but I can't seem to solve mine based on the answers there.

I want to be able to sort my list of projects in the index view by the `udtid` in the `entityudfstorage` table (class Ent), i.e., by `project.ent.udtid`. I have an additional consideration, in that each project matches a number of ent rows, so I need to scope to match to where `ent.rowindex != 0`.

The Models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ent, :foreign_key => "attachtoid"
has_many :samples, :foreign_key => "projectid"

class Ent < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name("entityudfstorage")
belongs_to :project, :foreign_key => "attachtoid"
scope :rowindex, where('entityudfstorage.rowindex != ? ', "0")
```

project index view:

```
    <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "name", "Name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "projecttype", "Project Type" %> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><%= project.name %></td>
    <td><%= project.ent.rowindex.first.udtid %></td>
    </tr>
```

project controller

```
def list
@projects = Project.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end
```

I've been trying to figure out what I can put in the "sort_column" for projecttype which would get it to sort by the associated field project.ent.rowindex.first.udtid (the same way that "name" works in the controller to sort by project.name).

I tried putting in a scope in projects of

```
 scope :by_udtids, Project.joins("left join ent on projects.projectid = ent.attachtoid").where('ent.rowindex != ?', 0).order("ent.udtid DESC")
```

and then tried this in the project controller.

```
if sort_column == "projecttype"
@projects = Project.by_udtids
else
@projects = Project.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

The result is that the project index page shows up with the proper data in the columns, but when I click on the "Project Type" link header, it does not sort (whereas, if I click on the "Name" link header, it does sort. The logs I can see in the server terminal are the same for both clicks, and the query's seem correct..

```
Started GET "/projects?direction=asc&sort=projecttype" for 128.208.10.200 at 2013-08-29 07:47:52 -0700
Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"direction"=>"asc", "sort"=>"projecttype"}
Project Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "project".* FROM "project" ORDER BY name asc
Ent Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "entityudfstorage".* FROM "entityudfstorage" WHERE "entityudfstorage"."attachtoid" = 602 AND (entityudfstorage.rowindex != '0' ) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "entityudfstorage".* FROM "entityudfstorage" WHERE "entityudfstorage"."attachtoid" = 602 AND (entityudfstorage.rowindex != '0' ) LIMIT 1
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sample" WHERE "sample"."projectid" = 602 
Ent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "entityudfstorage".* FROM "entityudfstorage" WHERE "entityudfstorage"."attachtoid" = 603 AND (entityudfstorage.rowindex != '0' ) LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "entityudfstorage".* FROM "entityudfstorage" WHERE "entityudfstorage"."attachtoid" = 603 AND (entityudfstorage.rowindex != '0' ) LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sample" WHERE "sample"."projectid" = 603

Rendered projects/list.html.erb within layouts/admin (478.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 487ms (Views: 398.7ms | ActiveRecord: 87.9ms)
[2013-08-29 07:55:27] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-   length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 128.208.10.200 at 2013-08-29 07:55:28 -0700
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-08-29 07:55:28] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-   length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Much appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually say what "doesn't work" means in this context. I would guess that it either means you get an error message or that the Projects aren't sorted the way you expect.

If it's an error message, you should include it with your question, but the first thing I'd do in your place is probably to start using the Rails conventions for naming and referring to things. If your associated class is `UserDefinedField`, Rails is going to expect the table to be named `user_defined_fields` and the association to be specified as `has_many :user_defined_fields`. It also expects *fields* to be in snake case (`attach_to_id`, not `attachtoid`), but aside from having to specify every foreign key everywhere, that probably won't cause errors. Looking at your code, I would expect Rails to be complaining about the association name any time it loaded the Project model. You should either change these things to match the conventions, or (if you have a good reason to use these names), tell Rails what's up by specifying the class and table names in your associations.

If it's an incorrect response order, I'm less certain what the issue is. One thing that jumps out immediately is that you're going to get the same Project returned multiple times with this scope, once for each associated UserDefinedField. If you don't want that to happen, you'll need to add a `group` clause to your scope and some sort of aggregation for the `userdefinedfields.udtids`. This might look something like:

```
scope :by_udtids, Project.
  joins("left join userdefinedfields on projects.projectid = userdefinedfields.attachtoid").
  where('userdefinedfields.rowindex != ?', 0).
  group('projects.id').
  order("max(userdefinedfields.udtid) DESC")
```

Edit:
It looks like your current problem is that the scope isn't getting used at all. Here's a couple of reasons that might be the case:

1. I notice that your controller action is called `ProjectsController#list`, but that your log says the request with the parameters is being processed by `ProjectsController#index`. The call to the `list` action doesn't appear to be running *any* queries, which sounds as though perhaps it isn't doing anything that triggers actually loading the objects. Could this simply be a routing or template error?
2. Given that you say the query being run is the same in both cases, if the correct action *is* being called, it seems likely that your conditional (`sort_column == "projecttype"`) is returning false, even when you pass the parameters. Even if the scope wasn't quite correct, you would otherwise still see at least a *different* query there. Is it possible that you're simply forgetting to set `sort_column = params[:sort]`? Try temporarily removing the conditional - just always use `@projects = Project.by_udtid`. See if you get a different query then.

Side note on the scope/query itself. If I understand your comment correctly, you want to sort by the `udtid` of the `Ent` with the lowest nonzero `rowindex`. This is going to be tricky, and the details will depend on your database (grouping, especially complex grouping, is one of the things that works fairly differently in mySQL vs. PostGreSQL, the two most common databases for Rails apps). The concept is called a 'groupwise maximum', and your best bet is probably to search for that phrase in conjunction with your database name.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback MrTheWalrus, I went back and edited my original post to hopefully clarify the question. I am working with a legacy database, and I had specified my foreign keys in the code but had left that out of the question. I believe that I am getting the correct scope (the fields render just fine), however, am not implementing correctly in the view in order to get the "sort" out of the controller. I will look into the group clause, though, as you mention, since I don't want to be bloating up the db queries. Thanks again!

Comment: @xyzzy Legacy databases are indeed on of the great tragedies of the profession. I've added some suggestions/thoughts based on your added information and comment. I hope it helps.